# returning execute with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a function that returns this :

```
function some(){
  ...
  return $this->query->execute();
}
```

And then I have this :

```
$var = some();
```

But when I try to fetch $var the page just wont load. Hope anyone can help me
I know execute is not empty because I'd fetch() the result inside some().

When I do var_dump to $var it returns bool(true)

Comment: You need to return $this->query instead. right now you're just returning the status of execute: true = successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns `bool` on whether or not it was successful, so this is correct functionality and it's letting you know that the query executed successfully.

What you need to return is either the result set:

```
$this->query->execute();
return $this->query->fetchAll();
```

Or the [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.php) object itself:

```
return $this->query;
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "fetch $var", exactly? The [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute) method returns a boolean value. `true` if it is successful or `false` if it fails. There is nothing to fetch from the return value of PDOStatement::execute(). You call fetch on your PDOStatement object.

If $this->query were your PDOStatement object in this code then you do...

```
$this->query->execute();
return $this->query
```

From your function and that would return the PDOStatement object that you can call the fetch method on. Or just fetch it from inside your function and return the result directly if that's what you want.